# check if an object exist into another array

Tags: typescript

I want to check if an object inside an array exist in another array, so for the below example the event array returns true, but the event1 array returns false.

> combination.some(a => event.every((v, i) => v.code == a[i].code))

```
let combination = [
  [
    { code: "repeatAdh", value: null },
    { code: "duplicatePartner", value: null }
  ]
];

let event = [
  { code: "repeatAdh", value: "Répéter adhérent par carte" },
  { code: "duplicatePartner", value: "Répéter conjoint" }
];

let event1 = [
  { code: "duplicatePartner", value: "Répéter conjoint" },
  { code: "repeatAdh", value: "Répéter adhérent par carte" }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have a built-in way to compare the value of different objects.

When you compare 2 objects, Javascript will check if they are 'the same' object, but not by value, by identity.

As an example, these 2 objects are not the same object.

```
const a = { foo: 'bar' };
const b = ( foo: 'bar' };

a === b // false
```

These 2 are the same:

```
const a = { foo: 'bar' };
const b = a;

a === b // true
```

In the second example, if you add a property to `a`, it also appears on `b`.

To compare 2 objects *by value*, you need to go through every property and see if they all match.

Answer (score 0):

Checking equality between objects in JavaScript is quite tricky. There is no a built-in function that can give you a straight answer. So first, you have to define what "equals" or "exists" means in your context.

For example, if you know that the objects you are going to check always have the same keys, you can say that they are equal if their values match. Given your example

```
function isEqual(a, b) {
    return (
        a.code === b.code && a.value === b.value
    )
}
```

Then you can create a function that will check that equality for every element on a list.

```
function listIsEqual(a, b) {
  return a.every(objA => 
    b.reduce((acc, objB) => 
      acc || isEqual(objA, objB)
    , false)
  );
}
```

You could check `event` against `event1` which would return `true`.

```
listIsEqual(event, event1)
> true
```

And you could use that function to check if the `event` exists on a list of `events`.

```
function objIsInList(target, list) {
  return list.some(object => listIsEqual(target, object));
}

objIsInList(event, combination)
> false

objIsInList(event1, combination)
> false

objIsInList(combination[0], combination)
> true
```

But, if your equality checks are more complicated, it would be best to use one of the existing solutions provided by libraries like lodash. Lodash provides a function called `isEqual` and `isEqualDeep` that can check equality between any objects. [Here is its documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual)

I hope it helps.